# IdentityServer3 Sample Client for multiple Authorities

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver3

Using the OWIN and Thinkecture components are very powerful.  I have an MVC app that is fully secured using an Identity Server we built on Thinkecture.  It can call our web api secured as a resource through our IDS.

We now have a new feature that we need to call out to a 3rd party and access their API to grab some data.  They also protect their api through oauth2 using their identity services. I thoght doing this would be straight forward, but I am struggling figuring out the actual code to do this.  Basically they request a page in our MVC app.  It requires authorization, but that is authorization from our IDS.  We lookup the access and refresh token to use for our user to call the 3rd party.  If not found or if it is expired, we need to authorize with the 3rd party by having the user login to their IDS, give consent, etc.

I could not find any client examples to handle this.  Can someone point me to an example or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I looked closer at the IdentityServer3 samples and found the MVC manual Code Flow client and dug into it a little bit.  I was able to take the code from there and alter it a little bit to save off nonce and state a different way and then was able to accomplish what I wanted.